# Detect lines in python

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have an images like that one with segmented parts of road lanes.

Seems that Hough transform is not good for such case.
I tried also to cluster points before line detection but seems that it's not good idea also.

What algorithm can be suitable for detecting such torn and thick lines?

[image]

Comment: Main question, I think, how to cluster that coords into different lanes. If that done, you can just use spline approx. methods to get lanes.